# Could not find the Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I have to setup Cloud SQL database.

The client has given login credentials for Google and Cloud SQL instance details. 
There is database and tables and data in tables there according to they. But how will I see the DB or Cloud SQL instance details from their account. I could not found it after login into the Google account.

I think the below URL will contain the details (on clicking Cloud SQL link on left side).
https://code.google.com/apis/console

Answer (score 0):

First off, instead of sharing account details, have the owner of the account [add you as a member to the project](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/projects).

Then, once you can confirm you can log in, you can try connecting to the database to see what is in there. If you're worried you can't see anything, try logging into the database as the root user (you may need to get the password from project owner if he/she has already set one). If you still can't see any data, it's likely there isn't any in there.